# cointegration tests for time series

Tags: time-series, cointegration

To test cointegration relationship for multiple time series, one usually writes the VAR(k) as
$$
\Delta y_t = \Pi y_{t-1} + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\Gamma_j\Delta y_{t-j} + e_t
$$
See, e.g.,
[https://www.uh.edu/~bsorense/coint2022.pdf](https://www.uh.edu/%7Ebsorense/coint2022.pdf)
According to the above lecture note and many textbooks, if $\Pi$ has full rank, then all $y_t$ must be stationary. Why?

The only answer that comes to me is that we pre-multiply all terms in the equation by $\Pi^{-1}$, and since all $\Delta y_t$ components are I(0), all $y_t$ components must be I(0).

I wonder if this argument is valid or if there is an easier way to understand this. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @john316. Your error-correction equation above is written in first-difference terms. The $\Pi$ matrix tells us how many linear combinations exist among the first-differenced variables. If $\Pi$ is full rank, it implies that there are n independent linear combinations of the variables that are stationary. This in turn implies that we can solve uniquely for each of the n variables in terms of stationary variables. So, overall, all the variables must be stationary in the first place, which implies a VAR in the levels.

Comment: @EB3112, your comment is an answer. Why not post it as one?

Comment: Thank you @EB3112 !!